# Advanced Laravel Query

Tags: sql, database, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Here is my Schema:

The `User` model is normal.

```
Question
  - team_id
  - question_body
```

```
Answer
  - user_id
  - question_id
  - order
  - is_private
```

A user can have a `primary` answer for a question which is essentially the answer that has the lowest `order` and is public.

I need to get the primary answer of a question for each user except the authenticated user. I have tried multiple ways but can't seem to figure it out. Here is what I have so far on the `Question` model:

```
public function topAnswerForEachMember()
{
    return $this->load(['answers' => function($query) {
        return $query->public()
            ->where('user_id', '!=', Auth::user()->getKey());
    }]);
}
```

This returns all public answers to the question not owned by the auth user. Now from here I need to get the one with the lowest order from each user. I have tried `groupBy` but am getting aggregate errors for that. I'm guessing this is going to require a sub query of sorts but I am unfamiliar with those. If anyone has an idea it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I think this may be easiest if you come at it from the *reverse*.  I would use the **User** model and pull your answers from there.  It is a simpler query.

I don't know exactly what your relations are, or what the `public()` method does, but something like this should be close to what you intended:

```
$users = User::whereHas('answers', function($query) use($question_id){
   $query->where('question_id', $question_id)
         ->orderBy('order', 'asc')->first();
})
  ->where('id', "!=", Auth::user()->id)
  ->get();
```

From here, each `user` in that collection should have a single, lowest ordered `answer` to the `question` you are looking into.  You can substitute `limit()` for `first()` if you wish to get more than one answer as well.